# Converting coordinate obtained from google maps to be used with gdal_translate in java or cs2cs?

Tags: coordinate-system, java, cs2cs

this is a follow on question from [Geo-Referencing an image from google maps with gdal_translate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174771/geo-referencing-an-image-from-google-maps-with-gdal-translate)

I am trying to get cs2cs to work but I am getting the following error.

My command is as follows:

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:3857 -f "%%.2f" <wgs.txt >merc.txt
```

And the output when using PROJ_DEBUG=5 is

```
pj_open_lib(epsg): call fopen(C:\Users\monke\Desktop\Trial\cs2cs\Bin/epsg) - succeeded
pj_open_lib(epsg): call fopen(C:\Users\monke\Desktop\Trial\cs2cs\Bin/epsg) - succeeded
pj_open_lib(@null): call fopen(C:\Users\monke\Desktop\Trial\cs2cs\Bin/@null) - failed
```

I have been at this for hours and haven't made any progress.

Failing a cs2cs solution, a solution using java would be great too.

Comment: Can you describe in what environment you start the command, and where you installed proj.4 or GDAL from?

Comment: @AndreJ So I am trying to do all this as a part of a standalone project so it is run from a regular Windows command prompt in a batch file.

Comment: If you run the command inside a OSGeo4W shell or gisinternals SDK shell, it should run out of the box. For a standalone project, you have to set the environment variables that are set in those shells.

Comment: I have come up with a solution using geotools in Java. Thanks for all that helped.